# How to add an array of roles to member at once discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, discord, discord.js

I want to add the "Auto-Role System" to my discord bot.
I was doing well but it went into an error, You can check the end of the article for errors.

What I want to do is:

1. The owner uses the command by mentioning a role or a bunch of roles
2. Bot stores them in an array and then saves it on the database
3. When a user joined the guild, the bot gives that roles array to a member

So at first, we need to make a model for the database so I did create one:

```js
// Guild.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const guildConfigSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  guildId: { type: String, match: /\d{18}/igm, required: true },
  autoRoleDisabled: {
    type: Boolean,
  },
  autoRoleRoles: {type: Array},
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('guild', guildConfigSchema);
```

Then I coded the setup command:

```js
        const role = message.mentions.roles.first();
        if (!role) return message.channel.send('Please Mention the Role you want to add to other Auto Roles.');
        Schema.findOne({ guildId: message.guild.id }, async (err, data) => {
            if (data) {
                data.autoRoleDisabled = false;
                data.autoRoleRoles.push(role.id);
                data.save();
            } else {
                new Schema({
                    guildId: message.guild.id,
                    autoRoleDisabled: false,
                    $push: { autoRoleRoles: role.id }
                }).save();
            }
            message.channel.send('Role Added: ' + `<@&${role.id}>`);
        })
```

In the end we need to make it work:

```js
// Main.js

client.on("guildMemberAdd", async (member) => {
  // ****Auto-Role****
  const Welcome = require('./models/Guild');
  try {
    Welcome.findOne({ guildId: member.guild.id }, async (err, data) => {
      if (!data) {
        return;
      } else {
        if (data.autoRoleDisabled == false) {
          let roles = data.autoRoleRoles;
          roles.forEach(r => {
            guildRrole = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id)
            member.roles.add(guildRrole);
          })
        } else {
          return;
        }
      }
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

But it doesn't work and gives an error:

```
Error: cyclic dependency detected
at serializeObject (C:\Users\Pooyan\Desktop\PDMBot\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:333:34)
```

And I think the problem is from pushing role IDs in the array.

Notes: I am using discord.js@13.8.0 and Node.js v16

Comment: that error means that as a result you got an object referencing to itself in some node

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: at least give the line where the error occurs, hard to tell only from that code

Comment: Ok, Check out my new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change

```js
   guildRrole = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id)
   member.roles.add(guildRrole);
```

to

```js
   guildRrole = member.guild.roles.cache.get(r);
   if (!guildRrole) return;
   member.roles.add(guildRrole);
```

because you are not finding role with id, you just did `.find(role => role.id)` which just gives `role id` so you have to check `role id` with your `role id` if you want to do with `.find()` like:

```js
.find((role) => {
 role.id === r
})
```